# Are my questions fitting the criteria of "Help Center > Asking"?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm not asking with respect to number of answers or lack of upvotes or whatever, because I saw a lot of duplicate questions in that category. I want to know what I'm doing wrong asking wise, because I find myself asking a question, wondering if it's too complicated or asked wrong, then a day later I end up answering it. I know that if I spend long enough on a problem I can solve it.

**My goal with this**

My desire is that by asking here it will take 2 hours instead of 8 or 9, and it'll give me a question I can go back to as a reference (also it might be useful to other people). I feel like my questions aren't up to par or maybe my sample size is just to small, but that's why I'm asking here for people to give me some feedback specific to me. Do my questions meet the criteria of the help center? And if they don't then why exactly.

Comment: Unless you have deleted questions, it doesn't look like you have any downvoted ones.  So that seems fine.

Comment: I did delete a question recently but i stumbled upon the answer 5 minutes after I asked through blind luck in my own research (I found a method that I previously thought was unrelated to my problem).

Comment: You are a student.  There are not going to be a lot of opportunities to burn 9 hours on a problem in your future career.  You'd better do it now while you have the chance.  And also keeping in mind that asking somebody else to do it for you is not going to have the same payoff.

Comment: I personally feel like its more efficient to learn from a teacher rather than slug everything out myself. Obviously a mix of both is preferred but I try to slug it out for 3 hours or so before I ask around. If that doesn't work then I set aside 8-9 hours to actually solve it. I just view it as an efficiency thing, when I'm struggling I think its better to ask than to not.

Comment: This question as written is rather broad to be honest. Too broad? Hard to tell. Mostly it is broad because you don't identify which aspect of your asking leads you to believe that your approach may be off topic, and as a result it is up to us to try to guess at what aspect you had in mind. Your questions on main seem fine to me, at least the ones I can see. Overall, I believe this question is strongly related to [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1026459), but I am not entirely convinced it is a duplicate.

Comment: One thing worth remembering is that SE responds to effort.  If we see effort, you get effort.  The more you show, the more you get.  Treat it like a valued resource full of experts you don't want to bother if you don't have to, and don't waste their time.  The attitude of, "It's faster for me for experts to teach me" doesn't do that.  Yes, it is.  But why should they, if you haven't shown any effort yourself?

Comment: @Travis J I checked out that link in your comment. It seems like there are two sides to that argument. Personally I believe that I should put in a "College try": Research, test code, google it, make sure you're not asking a duplicate and THEN ask. But I don't think trying so hard and getting frustrated before asking is good. I also try to research myself as the question is posted so I'm not just idly waiting for someone else. My thing is that SO to me is like a colleague, yes they've got their stuff to do but likely they can give you some pointers, especially if they're an expert.

Comment: I hope my questions don't exhibit an under researched quality. I do answer a lot of them myself because I keep working while the question is active. Plus I think dependency Injection is a useful topic (most of my questions are related to that right now). What would you guys consider reasonable in terms of time spent before asking?

Comment: A)thx for coming here with an open mind. Super refreshing.   B) SO is very helpful as one of the feathers in your cap (or a tool in your shed). But it's not the be all end all for all things programming. For instance, with the Q&A format and the quality standards, 'teaching' isn't something that will naturally come from your interactions on the site.  But that's besides the point of your question I know (just offering some peripheral observations)